# Resolving DUPLICATE for a column with UNIQUE

Tags: mysql, innodb, unique-constraint, duplication

I have a few column with `UNIQUE INDEX`. In some queries, duplicates should be acceptable, in which a postfix should be added to the value. For example, if `test title` exits, we change it to `test title-2`.

Is there a way to make a unique value upon `DUPLICATE`?

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (title, abr, name) 
  VALUES
  ('title', 'abr', 'name')
```

In this typical example, all three columns are `UNIQUE`. When the `INSERT` fails, I do not know which col caused the error to change its corresponding value.

How can I make a query to change `value` to `value-identifier` upon duplicate error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree with @BillThor that what you want to do may create some problems but what you need is ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement so your query would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1
(`title`, `abr`, `name`) 
VALUES
('title', 'abr', 'name')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title` = CONCAT(`title`, '-2');
```

You can change CONCAT to any other function or your own stored procedure.

Comment: How should I know that the duplicate is on the column `title`? it can be from columns `abr` or `name`, which are also `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Use stored procedure which will check if given value already exists and in such case will return updated value so it will be something like
... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title` = myTitleChecker(VALUES(`title`)), `abr` = myAbrChecker(VALUES(`abr`)), myNameChecker(VALUES(`name`));

Comment: now it seems to be a practical solution!

Answer (score 4):

I would look at your model first.  Placing a unique key constraint on a non-unique column gets you into this kind of problem.  What happens when you get a legitimate value like `test title-2` but you've already used that value to resolve a collision on `test title`.

If I had to resolve your problem, I would build a query for each unique key of the form:

```
SELECT  title
FROM    table1
WHERE   title STARTS WITH ?
```

The results will need to be parsed to see what the suffix should be.  It might be possible to do this in a stored procedure.  However, I would strongly argue that the data model needed to be fixed, not the code.